# python: multi SocketServer work in same time

Tags: python, serversocket

I want to make 3 SocketServer in one python program:

```
import threading
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class PolicyHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(128).strip()
        print self.data
        if self.data == '<policy-file-request/>\0':
            self.request.sendall('message 1')


class LiveRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.request.sendall('message 2')


def main():
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',80),\
                               SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpdThr = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    httpdThr.daemon = True
    httpdThr.start()

    liveServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',8090), LiveRequestHandler)
    livThr = threading.Thread(target=liveServer.serve_forever)
    livThr.daemon = True
    livThr.start()

    policyServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',834), PolicyHandler)
    policyThr = threading.Thread(target=policyServer.serve_forever)
    policyThr.daemon = True
    policyThr.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run it, the output below:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It's strange that it immediately exit the program, so my client program could not 
connect to the three socket server. how to prevent it to exit the program?

Comment: Have you seen the [asynchronous example](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins) in the `SocketServer` documentation?

Comment: yes, I have seen. it show one SocketServer to asynchronous handle multi request.

Comment: Yes, but you could use the same technique with putting the `handle_forever` call in a separate thread.

Comment: Does SocketServer can proactively send message to it's client out side it's handle() method?

Comment: In general, don't use threads just to listen to multiple sockets, there is the select() system call for that which avoids all multithreading headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daemon threads terminate when there are no more non-daemon threads running, so they exit when main ends.  Add something to keep main running, like:

```
raw_input('Press enter to stop servers.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to start the three servers from the same program, that would be one solution.

Answer (score 0):

now I change my code as below:

```
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',80), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpdThr = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
httpdThr.daemon = True
httpdThr.start()

liveServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',8090), LiveRequestHandler)
livThr = threading.Thread(target=liveServer.serve_forever)
livThr.daemon = True
livThr.start()

policyServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',834), PolicyHandler)
policyThr = threading.Thread(target=policyServer.serve_forever)
policyThr.daemon = True
policyThr.start()
```

it work fine. but now I do not know how to send message to the client when need.

Comment: You should amend your question rather than add more information as an answer.